# Parámetros que quedan con valores globales en Python

Tags: python, funciones, variables-globales

Tengo la siguiente función en Python

```
def listStrange(value, list=[]):
    lista.append(value)
    return list
```

La función es simple, añade un valor `value` sobre una lista `list`. Aparentemente, si no añades el parámetro `list`, esta toma por default una lista vacia.

Después, invoco lo siguiente para probar mi función

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    l1 = listStrange(2)
    l2 = listStrange(10,[])
    l3 = listStrange('a')
    print("l1 = {}".format(l1))
    print("l2 = {}".format(l2))
    print("l3 = {}".format(l3))
```

En teoría, yo pensaba que las salidas iban a ser `l1 = [2]` , `l2 = [10]` , `l3 = ['a']` respectivamente, pero me llevo la siguiente sorpresa

```
> python .\listStrange.py
l1 = [2, 'a']
l2 = [10]
l3 = [2, 'a']
```

Al parecer, la variable default se queda como global. Cuando se llama por primera vez para "l1", esta empieza vacia y al final queda como `[2]`, pero al ser llamada nuevamente para "l3", esta queda con el valor anterior de `[2]` para finalmente obtener la salida de `[2, 'a']`. Como esta fue la lista default para "l1" y "l3", este valor se replica en ambas variables.

Quisiera saber alguna documentación que mencione la justificación técnica de este comportamiento, o al menos, como llamarlo. Lo he buscado como "variables globales python en parámetros" pero no encuentro algún ejemplo similar o explicación que me ayude a clarificar porque sucede esto.

Comment: Este link hace mencion de lo que esta sucediendote! https://sodocumentation.net/es/python/topic/3553/errores-comunes

Comment: Como documentación técnica, puedes mirar lo que dice la FAQ oficial: https://docs.python.org/3.9/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects Se puede ver como un problema o como una ventaja, un modo de _"compartir valores entre objetos_" sin usar variables globales. (nombre: _"shared default values between object"_).

Answer (score 2):

El problema se reduce a esto:

```
def fcn(lista = []):
    print(len(lista))
    lista.append('*')
fcn()
fcn()
```

produce:

```
0
1
```

O sea, la lista va creciendo en cada llamada. ¿Por qué?

Los argumentos por omisión de una función se evalúan en el momento en que Python lee la `def`. En este caso, el argumento es una lista vacía.

Una vez evaluado el argumento (la lista vacia), en las siguientes llamadas se ocupa el valor obtenido, **no** se vuelve a calcular o generar de nuevo.

Como la lista ya fue creada y aun existe, Python la vuelve a ocupar y la lista crece.

**La forma correcta**

La forma correcta es inicializar el argumento con `None` y crear la lista (u objeto requerido) dentro de la función:

```
def fcn2(lista = None):
    if lista is None:
        lista = []
    print(len(lista))
    lista.append("*")

fcn2()
fcn2()
```

produce:

```
0
0
```

En esta otra implementación, en cada llamada a `fcn2()` sin pasar el argumento `lista`, ésta adquiere el valor `None`. Al entrar a la función entonces, `lista` vuelve a inicializar con `[]`.

Probemos pasando una lista explícitamente:

```
lista = []
fcn2(lista)
fcn2(lista)
```

produce:

```
0
1
```

Moraleja: los valores por omisión en la declaración de una función debe ser tipos *inmutables*.